# unnest_longer gives dollar sign instead of normal tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

can anybody explain the following difference:

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~id,
    c(1:10))%>%
unnest_longer(id)%>%
mutate(data = map(.x = id, ~mtcars))%>%
unnest_longer(data)
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 320 x 2
   id data$mpg  $cyl $disp   $hp $drat   $wt $qsec   $vs   $am $gear $carb
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2     1     21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3     1     22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4     1     21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5     1     18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

whereas

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~id,
    c(1:10))%>%
unnest_longer(id)%>%
mutate(data = map(.x = id, ~mtcars))%>%
unnest(data)
```

gives the result I want.

```
      # A tibble: 320 x 12
       id   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2     1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3     1  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4     1  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5     1  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

Why are there $-Signs in the 1st example of code? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first one gives you some kind of a data.frame nested in a data.frame, that's why you got `A tibble: 320 x 2`. You have to access the data of `data` by `df$data$mpg`. The second one unnests the whole data and gives you a `A tibble: 320 x 12`. You can access the data via `df$mpg`.

Comment: thanks. But how can I use unnest_longer to get the 2nd result? Or is this the wrong idea and I should stay with unnest?

Comment: Does anyone know why we get those dollar signs in the column names? unnest_longer adds them while base unnest doesn't which is what I would like it to work.

Comment: I just use unnest. Maybe pull() helps ...cant test at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in `{tibble}` version 2.0.1 - [docs](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/01/tibble-2.0.1/#2d-columns).

To get the same results as `tidyr::unnest()`, you'll need to add `tidyr::unpack()`.

```
tribble(
  ~id,
  c(1:10)
) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_longer(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(data = purrr::map(
    .x = id,
    ~ mtcars
  )) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_longer(data) %>% 
  tidyr::unpack(cols = data)
```

Comment: nice! will try that one.