# Removing nested data frame structure after unnesting data frames

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

After unnesting a list of data.frames columns using `unnest_longer`, the columns from the unnested data frame seem to retain some sort of data frame structure.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
    # data
    d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
    d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
    my_df <- tibble(some_data = list(d1, d2), id = c("d1", "d2"))
    
    # Unnesting
    result <- my_df %>%
      unnest_longer(some_data)
    
    names(result) # expecting "y1", "y2", "id"
```

I would expect the column names to be "y1, "y2" and "id" not "some_data"
and "id". Removing this data structure would quicker analysis on the tibble using `dplyr` (e.g., selecting, grouping)

Same as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328384/unnest-longer-gives-dollar-sign-instead-of-normal-tibble)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my_df %>%
   unnest(c(some_data))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     y1    y2 id   
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     4 d1   
#2     2     5 d1   
#3     3     6 d1   
#4     3     6 d2   
#5     2     5 d2   
#6     1     4 d2
```

Comment: Brilliant! Upvoted! By the way, do we need `c()` or we can just run without it?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks.  You can use without it.  I do it because of a habit.